# How to test a Live-CD/USB + add drivers for Broadcom wireless card + reboot and continue the Live-CD/USB testing?

Tags: drivers, live-cd, live-usb

Is it possible to test a Live-CD/USB by booting from it, adding drivers for a Broadcom wireless card, rebooting after that and have the drivers installed to keep on testing the Live-CD/USB?

Comment: No,you can't just enable the drivers from a default configured live usb drive. as of ubuntu 12.04 nightly builds. There are some bugs that make it a living hell. I tried installing them and configuring them with UCK, they don't work. :(

Answer (score 3):

This is a very similar question as [this AU Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key) and step-by-step answer.

Ignore the "nightly download" part of the answer - just use the ISO you have downloaded to install onto a USB stick.

Once installed, you can Activate the broadcom drivers in the Additional Hardware window.

Comment: Clever :-)  Will try.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about doing refers to having a persistent USB Drive. With what you currently are using yes, you can reboot it but no, you won't be able to save anything to it. An option have though is to make a LiveUSB that is able to be persistent, (Able to hold changes and save them, like saving a word document etc.) then you'd most likely be able to do what you're asking. To do this I recommend you use a USB Flash drive that has a minimum of 4GB of free memory, preferably 8GB if you have it. A (hopefully anyway) simple way to do this follows.

*Please Note: This tutorial is based for those with Windows Systems, and are trying out GNU/Linux on the aforementioned system.*

### What You Will Need

- The Universal USB Installer Program.
- A computer with an Internet Connection.
- A GNU/Linux ISO image. Ubuntu, Fedora, Kubuntu, Etc...

### What To Do

1. [DOWNLOAD](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) or run the Universal USB Installer Program.
2. Browse and select your chosen GNU/Linux ISO Image. *NOTE: If you don't have one you will be given the option to download it before writing it to your chosen drive.*
3. Browse for and select your chosen USB Flash Drive.
4. **MAKE SURE** you have chosen the right flash/external drive **BEFORE** you write the ISO image to it as **ALL** data will be lost when this process is completed!!!
5. Write the ISO image to the flash drive, choosing if you wish to have a persistent storage and if so how much memory to allocate for said storage.
6. Restart your computer with the flash drive connected, boot to the flash drive, and enjoy your external USB Drive!
   Hope this helps you!

*P.S. If you need more info please do not hesitate to let me know...*